# Submitting tinyMCE textarea to database using serialize method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit different form input fields to database using serialize method. I am using tinyMCE on my textarea. After researching on this, I can now submit all the fields to the database except the textarea. I don't know why it is not being serialized. What should I do to my codes to get the textarea content to the database? My codes are shown below

**Form**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="myPage.php">
    <textarea class="tinymce" name="texteditor" id="texteditor"></textarea>

    <input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="A">
    <input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="B">
    <input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="C">
    <input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="D">

    <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    <input name="points" type="text" class="form-control" />

    <input name="random" type="radio" value="no" /> No <br>
    <input name="random" type="radio" value="yes" /> Yes

    <button id="sub" name="upload"><b>Submit</b></button>

</form>
```

**Java Script**

```
$("#sub").click( function() {

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm").serialize(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
    clearInput();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {
  $("#myForm").each( function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST["get_value"])){
  foreach($_POST["get_value"] as $checkbox){
  }
$question = $_POST['texteditor'];
$random = $_POST['random'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$points = $_POST['points'];

$insert_question = "insert into questions (question,checkbox,random,category,points) values ('$question','$checkbox','$random','$category','$points')";

$run_question = mysqli_query($con, $insert_question);
if($insert_question){
    echo "Question set successfully";
}
else {
    echo "failed";
}
}

else{
echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one option!')</script>";
}
```

Comment: So whats happening? fyi, your code will break if you have `'` in any of your values.. because its open to SQL injection.

Comment: Also you should be checking for `if($run_question){` not `if($insert_question){`, which is prob why you're getting a false positive on the insert.

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

In your click event first get value of tinymice then assign to text area
You can get the value/content of the tiny mice editor using any of the below method

```
    // Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
  var content =   tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

    // Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
  var content =     tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

    // Get content of a specific editor:
  var content =     tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

and then by jquery assign the content value to textarea something like

```
$('textarea[name=textarea]').val(content);
```

then do the process of serializing form and so on..

You can also try autosave plugin of Tinymice

Comment: Thanks LogicBlower for your quick response. Applying your answer i added var content =   tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); after $("#sub").click( function() { , but where should I add $('textarea[name=textarea]').val(content); in my code as i am new in jquery?

Comment: It worked. I did $("#sub").click( function() { var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); $('textarea[name=texteditor]').val(content); Thanks

Comment: Glad , it worked. you can Upvote my answer . so that other knows problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $("#sub").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//it will prevent ur form submit by default

        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm").serialize(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
        clearInput();
        });

        $("#myForm").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });

function clearInput() {
  $("#myForm").each( function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
}
```